# Intuition of Rectifiable Sets

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

I just got introduced to rectifiable sets and the def: The set S is rectifiable if the boundary of S is of measure zero.

This does not really help me understand what a rectifiable set is really and I want a good understanding of it. And does rectifiable set can be included in a set of a union of countable rectangles? And how does this definition relate to existance of $\int_S 1$?

Answer (score 0):

Some examples in one dimension:

The simplest example of a set we would like to call rectifyable would be if $S$ is the finite union of some rectangles (i.e., intervals). Then $\partial S$ is just the finite set of interval endpoints and so of measure zero. And of course $\int_S1=\mu(S)$ is just the sum of the interval lengths.

Now let $S=\Bbb Q\cap [0,1]$ be the set of rationals in the unit intervals. Then $\partial S=[0,1]$ is not a zero set. While we can approximate $S$ by a number of intervals, and in fact can cover $S$ by countably many intervals of arbitrarily small positive total length, we may not want to call $S$ rectifyable. Nevertheless, $\int_S1=\mu(S)=0$ clearly exists.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially a bounded set $S\subset\Bbb R^n$ is "rectifiable" by this definition iff
$$\int_S1$$
exists as a **Riemann** integral. That is $\chi_S$, the indicator function of $S$
which is $1$ on $S$ and $0$ off it, is a Riemann integrable function.

This is a special case of the theorem that a bounded function on a bounded subset
of $\Bbb R^n$ is Riemann integrable iff if is Lebesgue measurable and its set
of discontinuities has Lebesgue measure zero.